# Create proportional pivot table with multiple variables in R

Tags: r, pivot-table, percentage

I'm trying to create a pivot table out of the following data:

```
Scan Distance NOFO  ID
  1      1.0  NANA  A12
  2      1.0  NANA  A10
  3      2.0  HAHT  A12
  4      4.0  TANA  A1
  5      1.0  TANA  A3
  6      0.5  TATA  A1
```

I want the proportions of NOFO per each Distance and ID.

I've tried using ftable, dcast and tapply functions and am able to do it for NOFO ~ Distance:

```
prop.table(table(df$NOFO, df$Distance, useNA = "ifany")))
```

**Example result**:

```
        0.5          1            2           4       
 HAHT   0.003012048  0.000000000  0.000000000 0.003012048
 NANA   0.000000000  0.000000000  0.003012048 0.000000000
 TANA   0.000000000  0.000000000  0.003012048 0.003012048
 TATA   0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000 0.000000000
```

But I haven't been able to figure out a solution for NOFO ~ Distance + ID, so that each Distance proportion is split per ID.

Comment: can you post your code for `NOFO ~ Distance` which worked?

Comment: Do you need `prop.table(acast(df1, NOFO~Distance + ID, value.var="NOFO", length))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `ID` as a third variable.

```
prop.table(table(df$NOFO, df$Distance, df$ID, useNA = "ifany"))
, ,  = A1


             0.5         1         2         4
  HAHT 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
  NANA 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
  TANA 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1666667
  TATA 0.1666667 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000

, ,  = A10


             0.5         1         2         4
  HAHT 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
  NANA 0.0000000 0.1666667 0.0000000 0.0000000
  TANA 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
  TATA 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000

, ,  = A12


             0.5         1         2         4
  HAHT 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1666667 0.0000000
  NANA 0.0000000 0.1666667 0.0000000 0.0000000
  TANA 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
  TATA 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000

, ,  = A3


             0.5         1         2         4
  HAHT 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
  NANA 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
  TANA 0.0000000 0.1666667 0.0000000 0.0000000
  TATA 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

or if you prefer a flat table

```
> ftable(.Last.value)
                 A1       A10       A12        A3

HAHT 0.5  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
     1    0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
     2    0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1666667 0.0000000
     4    0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
NANA 0.5  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
     1    0.0000000 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.0000000
     2    0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
     4    0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
TANA 0.5  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
     1    0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1666667
     2    0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
     4    0.1666667 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
TATA 0.5  0.1666667 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
     1    0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
     2    0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
     4    0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```